# Why listview is not Scroll inside Relative Layout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, android-framelayout

I am trying to scroll the list whose id is list.I try almost all the solution but noting work for me.I try to put the Relative layout inside the scroll view but it also not work for me.I also try to put the listview inside the scroll view but it also not work.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <TextView
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/grp_heading"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/chat_item_rcv" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/primary"
    />

     <com.example.covite.chat_layout.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:ft_container_gravity="center"
    app:ft_color="@color/primary">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_menu"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.valuevision.covite.chat_layout.BottomSheetLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/send_message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#ffdddddd"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you set `RelativeLayout`  instead of `FrameLayout`

Comment: why you are using frame layout

Comment: thanks for the reply @AnjaliTripathi when i change my FrameLayout with the RelativeLayout but it not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

I assume `FrameLayout` creating this problem.

1. **Use RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout**
2. Call `ListView` out side of `RelativeLayout`

Hope this helps .

Comment: thanks for the reply @IntelliJ i try this but it not work

Comment: @ShubhankGupta You can set ListView `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: @ShubhankGupta Ji , You can try with `LinearLayout`

Comment: it not working with Linear layout i also change the height of listview at match_parent

Comment: @ShubhankGupta You can use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @ShubhankGupta For testing case you can add this (Listview) `android:layout_height="40dp"` . Check scrolling

Comment: @ShubhankGupta Ji Solve yet ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but my problem is  not resolve

Comment: @ShubhankGupta Ji , If you solved this problem , let me inform . I tried .

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout height containing your `listview` to `match_parent`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and your listview height to match_parent

```
<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also make sure that the list items you supply to the `listview` is long enough for you to scroll. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
I am not sure what `BottomSheetLayout` is about, but try set its layout height to match_parent as well.

```
<com.example.covite.chat_layout.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:ft_container_gravity="center"
    app:ft_color="@color/primary">
```

OR if possible move your `listview` out of `BottomSheetLayout`, and make it a child for your `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i try this it doesn't work for me